# How to Put tabGroup Inside Window or View Titanium Mobile

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

i make simple login and menu display in titanium mobile. here's my code for login:

Login.js

```
function Login() {
    var loginView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor:'#C4FBFF',
        layout:'vertical'
    });

    var txtUsername = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        width:'75%',
        hintText:'Username',
        borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
    });

    var txtPassword = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        width:'75%',
        hintText:'Password',
        borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
        passwordMask:true
    });

    var btnLogin = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title:'Login',
        width:'75%'
    });

    loginView.add(txtUsername);
    loginView.add(txtPassword);
    loginView.add(btnLogin);

    btnLogin.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({ 
            title: 'Confirmation', 
            message: 'You will be logged in as ' + txtUsername.value + ', continue?',
            buttonNames: ['Yes','No'] 
        });

        alertDialog.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            if (e.index === 0){ //Yes Pressed
                var isAndroid = Ti.Platform.osname === 'android' ? true : false;
                var MainMenu = isAndroid === true ? require('ui/handheld/android/MainMenu') : require('ui/handheld/MainMenu');

                var mainMenuWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                    backgroundColor:'#336699',
                    title:'Main Menu',
                    modal:true,
                    navBarHidden: isAndroid === true ? true : false
                });

                var mainMenu = new MainMenu(mainMenuWindow);
                mainMenuWindow.add(mainMenu);

                mainMenuWindow.open();

            }
            else{ // No Pressed
                makeAlert('Login','Please contact your system administrator');
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    });

    function makeAlert(title, message) {
        var customAlertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({ 
            title: title, 
            message: message,
            buttonNames: ['Ok']
        });
        return customAlertDialog.show();
    }

    return loginView;
}

module.exports = Login;
```

and here's MainMenu.js

```
function MainMenu(_parent){
    var mainMenuView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor:'#C4FBFF',
        layout:'vertical'
    });

    var btnLeftNavBar = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title:'Logout'
    });

    var txtTest = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        hintText:'iPhone',
        width:'75%',
        borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
    });

    _parent.setLeftNavButton(btnLeftNavBar);
    mainMenuView.add(txtTest);  

    btnLeftNavBar.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        _parent.close();
    });

    return mainMenuView;
}

module.exports = MainMenu;
```

MainMenu.js only displayed one button on navBar for close the window..

the main problem is i want to put tabGroup on MainMenu.js so i can choose some menu from it.

is it possible to put tabGroup inside the window? any suggestion, so i can put the tabGroup in MainMenu.js without changing the main application structure?

many thanks..

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to add a tabgroup as a children of any other element.
Reference: [Top Level Containers @ add method of tabgroup](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-add)

Text:

> Top-Level Containers
>
> There are certain top-level containers that are not intended to be
>   added as the children of other views. These top-level containers
>   include Window, SplitWindow, and TabGroup. Other types of views must
>   be added to a top-level container in order to be displayed on screen.

Comment: I was getting an error, and this solution helped me see that I had 2 Windows. Cheers!